# String Creation

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a question about string creation in a loop following is a code sample:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++)
        {
            Add(GetStr());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("hmmmmmmmm");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string GetStr()
    {
        return "OK";            
    }

    public static void Add(string str)
    {
        list.Add(str);
    }
```

How many number of strings will be created in memory in case of above code ???

Comment: Long-term: *one*, due to [string interning](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/08/understanding-c-stringintern-m.html).  Although each time `GetStr` is called, a string will be allocated before it is interned, and then be garbage collected.

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed as duplicate. The referenced question is about dynamic strings. This question is about a *constant string literal*. `"OK"` will be translated into the `LDSTR` IL opcode which pushes a reference to a string **stored in metadata**. So only one string will be allocated. *No temporary strings will be allocated* before being interned.

Comment: @BassamAlugili: Well 10 billion references in a list is quite alot :-)

Comment: @MårtenWikström yeah the exception cam before 10 billion I have also saw the IL code one string and it will be referenced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How many number of strings will be created in memory in case of above code

One. (or actually two if you include `"hmmmmmmmm"`)

This method returns a **constant string literal**:

```
public static string GetStr()
{
    return "OK";            
}
```

It is compiled into something like the following IL code:

```
ldstr "OK"
ret
```

The [LDSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldstr.aspx) opcode will push a reference to a string literal **stored in  metadata** and the [RET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ret.aspx) opcode will return that reference.

This means that `"OK"` will only be allocated *once* in the metadata. All  entries in the list will refer to that instance.

Notice that string literals are interned by default. So no "temporary string" will be allocated before being interned and therefore no garbage collection is needed.

Comment: I changed GetStr() code little bit and it created 1000000 plus strings 

            byte[] bytes=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("OK");
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

Comment: @RoyaanKhan: Ok. Well then you force the system to dynamically allocate a new string each time. `"OK"` will still be a reference to a string stored in metadata. However, `UTF.GetString(bytes)` will allocate a new string instance each time it is invoked.

Answer (score 5):

I have modified your code so that you can see the Memory addrese of the string "OK"

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
  using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

  public class Program
  {
    static unsafe Collection<string> list = new Collection<string>();

    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
      for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
      {
        Add(GetStr());
      }

      foreach (var str in list)
      {
        fixed (char* ptr = str)
        {
          var addr = (IntPtr)ptr;
          Console.WriteLine(addr.ToString("x"));
        }
      }

      Console.WriteLine("hmmmmmmmm");
      Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public unsafe static string GetStr()
    {
      return "OK";
    }

    public unsafe static void Add(string str)
    {
      list.Add(str);
    }
  }
}
```

------------ Console Output ------------------------

As you see the list use the same memory reference for the string "Ok".

```
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
#225bf54
hmmmmmmmm
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case there will be 2 strings created by your code: "OK" and "hmmmmmmmm". Because string a an immutable type the "OK" will only be created once, and every time you need it the string will just be referenced.

Comment: The fact that a `string` is an immutable type and the fact that it 's created only once is "connected" but it isn't a "A implies B", it's more "because A, we (.NET creators) could do B and we did B".

Comment: thanks @peer for me this tip is the answer " Because string a an immutable type will be created once" +1